# a non-responsive email parsing python code

Tags: python, email, parsing, pop3

I get this code from this forum for parsing email from my gmail account.

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('username')
pop_conn.pass_('password')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
print messages
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
    print message['subject']
pop_conn.quit()
```

But nothing happen after I run it on a notebook with username and password replaced. 
I only know that it is working to the point of checking the password as I get an error with a wrong password. I want to replace the line

```
"print message['subject']"
```

with something from the email.parser class. But I need to get this code working first. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn on the ability to connect over POP in your gmail settings. Or try using the port number '995' in the poplib.POP3_SSL(...)